# Highcharts object won't work when filled in a loop

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am making a sort of alternative to a drilldown in Highcharts that lets a user click on buttons to change the chart series displayed instead of clicking on data points. In order to do this, I am creating Highcharts buttons dynamically to the "exporting" section of the chart. The buttons should change the series displayed on the chart when clicked.

This works when the button object is not made in a loop. You can click the circles to change the series displayed:

```js
const series0 = [{ name: "blu", data: [39.11, 18.64, -1.6, 14.18, 8.83, 12.31, -6.03], color: "blue" }, { name: "bla", data: [27.97, 1.57, -1.01, 13.84, 8.01, 17.57, 2.41], color: "black" }];
const series1 = [{ name: "ora", data: [25.37, 22.29, 8.22, 17.51, -34.73, 5.44, -11.07], color: "orange" }, { name: "gr", data: [25.89, -3.97, 14.24, 13.3, 5.84, 35.23, -12.61], color: "green" }];
const series2 = [{ name: "red", data: [55.37, 2.29, 22, 75, -37, 5, -7], color: "red" }, { name: "sil", data: [29, -97, 14, 13, 5, 33, -11], color: "silver" }];
const series3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(series0));

const nameArray = ['1', '2', '3'];

const seriesContainer = [];
seriesContainer.push(series1);
seriesContainer.push(series2);
seriesContainer.push(series3);

var buttonContainerTest = new Object();

buttonContainerTest.back = {
  x: -34,
  onclick: function () {
    var chart = this;
    chart.update({ series: series3 }, true, true);
    $('.backButton').hide();
    $('.myButton').show();
    chart.redraw();
  },
  text: 'back',
  theme: {
    class: "backButton highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal"
  }
};

var xButtonPosition = -34;

buttonContainerTest['button' + nameArray[0]] = {
  x: -34,
  onclick: function () {
    var chart = this;
    chart.update({ series: seriesContainer[0] }, true, true);
    $('.backButton').show();
    $('.myButton').hide();
    chart.redraw();
  },
  symbol: 'circle',
  symbolFill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
  theme: {
    class: "myButton highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal"
  }
};

buttonContainerTest['button' + nameArray[1]] = {
  x: -54,
  onclick: function () {
    var chart = this;
    chart.update({ series: seriesContainer[1] }, true, true);
    $('.backButton').show();
    $('.myButton').hide();
    chart.redraw();
  },
  symbol: 'circle',
  symbolFill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
  theme: {
    class: "myButton highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal"
  }
};

var buttonObjectTest = {
  buttons: buttonContainerTest
};

console.log(buttonObjectTest);

$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },        
        
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },        
        
        series: series0,
        
        exporting: buttonObjectTest
    }, 

    );
});

$(function() {
   $('.backButton').hide();
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

This does not work, however, when the exact same object is made in a loop. Printing the object to the console doesn't help me see the difference:

```js
const series0 = [{ name: "blu", data: [39.11, 18.64, -1.6, 14.18, 8.83, 12.31, -6.03], color: "blue" }, { name: "bla", data: [27.97, 1.57, -1.01, 13.84, 8.01, 17.57, 2.41], color: "black" }];
const series1 = [{ name: "ora", data: [25.37, 22.29, 8.22, 17.51, -34.73, 5.44, -11.07], color: "orange" }, { name: "gr", data: [25.89, -3.97, 14.24, 13.3, 5.84, 35.23, -12.61], color: "green" }];
const series2 = [{ name: "red", data: [55.37, 2.29, 22, 75, -37, 5, -7], color: "red" }, { name: "sil", data: [29, -97, 14, 13, 5, 33, -11], color: "silver" }];
const series3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(series0));

const nameArray = ['1', '2', '3'];

const seriesContainer = [];
seriesContainer.push(series1);
seriesContainer.push(series2);
seriesContainer.push(series3);

var buttonContainerTest = new Object();

buttonContainerTest.back = {
  x: -34,
  onclick: function () {
    var chart = this;
    chart.update({ series: series3 }, true, true);
    $('.backButton').hide();
    $('.myButton').show();
    chart.redraw();
  },
  text: 'back',
  theme: {
    class: "backButton highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal"
  }
};

var xButtonPosition = -34;

for (i = 0; i < seriesContainer.length; i++) {
  var name = 'button' + nameArray[i];
  buttonContainerTest[name] = {
    x: xButtonPosition,
    onclick: function () {
      var chart = this;
      chart.update({ series: seriesContainer[i] }, true, true);
      $('.backButton').hide();
      $('.myButton').show();
      chart.redraw();
    },
    symbol: 'circle',
    symbolFill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
    theme: {
      class: "myButton highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal"
    }
  };
  xButtonPosition -= 20;
};

var buttonObjectTest = {
  buttons: buttonContainerTest
};

console.log(buttonObjectTest);

$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },        
        
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },        
        
        series: series0,
        
        exporting: buttonObjectTest
    }, 

    );
});

$(function() {
   $('.backButton').hide();
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

I get the feeling this is more of a general JavaScript issue than a Highcharts quirk. What am I missing?

I have already made a drilldown and do not want advice on making a drilldown if it means having to click individual data points. I would like this design here to work dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem which you are struggling with is that the 'i' value is equal 3 while click function is triggering. Notice that loop finished job, objects were created and 'i' stop variable as a 3 and seriesContainer[3] in your case is equal undefined.

Another problem is that the buttons have "this" refers to the chart, not to button themselves, so it's hard to find which one was triggered.

As a solution, I can suggest adding a current 'i' value to the class name when it is created and working on event to detect which button was clicked. See below:

```
  buttonContainerTest[name] = {
    x: xButtonPosition,
    onclick: function(e) {
        var chart = this,
                seriesNumberAr = e.target.parentNode.className.animVal.split(''),
            seriesNumberVal = seriesNumberAr[seriesNumberAr.length - 1];

      chart.update({
        series: seriesContainer[seriesNumberVal]
      }, true, true);
      $('.backButton').hide();
      $('.myButton').show();
      chart.redraw();
    },
    symbol: 'circle',
    symbolFill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
    theme: {
      class: "myButton highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal" + i
    }
  };
```

See demo: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1e5620cb/)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The code works well in this fiddle. The way this works is a bit nebulous to me, however, and I'd like to understand better. If you can point to a good resource for learning about events like this, that would be helpful. Also, I don't understand the reason the back button isn't working even if I activate Jquery. The biggest problem I'm having though is that when I use my real data, even copied by value, the series become malformed after a few clicks. Unfortunately I can't replicate that with dummy data, and the issue may have to be a new post.

Comment: @voluntier - I think that one of the best resources of learning is working as much as possible with the official documentation (like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)  and trying to understand it - about the back button - it seems like buttons created this way needs to have same class, see: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cjvw8pz4/. - back to your issue with your data - I am afraid that I am not able to help until you recreate the problem

Comment: Oh, you had the hide and show for the back button reversed. This is your example working the way I wanted it to with no issues: https://jsfiddle.net/czt7190x/. Thanks for the information. I understand about not being able to help with the series malformation issue. It only seems to happen for the series connected with the back button with my real data. I'll update if I can replicate it.

Comment: Ok, so I am waiting for the demo.

Comment: I still haven't identified the issue, but I found it was only happening for two series. When those series were clicked, they mutated the other series. The issue went away when I enabled boost.js, a highcharts extension that optimizes the loading of many data points. The series didn't have many points, but had some large values. I still can't replicate, and not sure why boost would fix. Other than that, the full code shouldn't be that different from the example. It has information I can't share publicly and is sourced from a database. If any new theories, let me know, but if not, no worries.

Comment: Interesting. Boost module deactivates some functionalities of the chart, like animation, maybe animation was breaking your chart - I can only guess without debugging it... If you will be able to recreate the problem - back to us. We are willing to help - Highcharts support team!